# Explanation of Kamatz vs. Patach ה הידעה

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk, vowels-nekudot

I've noticed that possukim will switch back and forth between the vowelizing of the definite article heh, sometimes multiple times within the same possuk. Is there a rule for this or an explanation in Chazal for the switching between kamatz and patach?

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: What letter follows the He in which cases?

Comment: Indeed, words starting with vowels and gutturals...

Comment: I was debating about providing specific examples but the switching seemed prevalent enough that it felt superfluous. Also, I'm on a phone and don't have nekudos on this keyboard.

Comment: If possible, I would like to add to the question, why החג (Divrei hayamim 2 7:8) is written with segol, while החסד (Devarim 7:12) and החשמל (Yechezkel 1:4) with patach?

Comment: Generally speaking it should be a Kamatz only if the next letter is א ר and sometimes ע. Does that satisfy all your examples? It's hard to tell without more details of what you're seeing

Comment: Are you limiting the answer to hazal?

Comment: How is asking about dikduk of Tanach off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

The rule is:

The definite article is הַ (usually) followed by dagesh hazaq (e.g. הַמַּיִם), unless the word starts with אהח"ע or (usually) ר, in which case the default is הָ (e.g. הָאָדָם).

If the word starts with חָ, unstressed עָ or unstressed הָ, the definite article becomes הֶ (e.g. הֶחָד or הֶעָנָן). In other cases of words starting with ח or ה, the definite article takes the usual form הַ (e.g. הַחַשְׁמַל).